# How to add another column

Tags: text-processing

I am trying to turn a file like this to something at the bottom. I am unsure of how to use awk or paste to go about this.

```
0.0000000000  0.0000000000  0.0000000000 
0.7804643317  0.5703578412   0.0000000000 
-0.7804643317  0.5703578412   0.0000000000
```

I would be dealing with a changing number of rows for the file I'm trying to transform.

```
0.0000000000 0  0.0000000000 0  0.0000000000 0
0.7804643317 0  0.5703578412 0  0.0000000000 0
-0.7804643317 0  0.5703578412 0  0.0000000000 0
```

Comment: I think you meant "the number of rows would stay at three, but the number of columns would change"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Perl approach:

```
$ perl -ane 'print "$_ 0 " for @F; print "\n"' file
0.0000000000 0 0.0000000000 0 0.0000000000 0 
0.7804643317 0 0.5703578412 0 0.0000000000 0 
-0.7804643317 0 0.5703578412 0 0.0000000000 0
```

Or, to edit the original file:

```
perl -i -ane 'print "$_ 0 " for @F; print "\n"' file
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd use **`sed`**:

```
sed -i -E 's/([^ ]+)/\1 0/g' file
```

or if the file is tab-delimited:

```
sed -i -E 's/([^\t]+)/\1\t0/g' file
```

- `-i` edit file inplace.
- `s/pattern/replacement/` means substitute pattern with a replacement string.

---

OR **`awk`**

```
awk -i inplace '{for (f=1;f<=NF; f++){$f=$f" 0"}}1' file
```

or

```
awk -i inplace '{for (f=1;f<=NF; f++){$f=$f"\t0"}}1' file
```

However, most implementations do not support `-i inplace`. Then, you need to write your output to a temp file and overwrite the original file with that:

```
awk '{for (f=1;f<=NF; f++){$f=$f" 0"}}1' file > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file
```

Answer (score 0):

Added help from:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11801/replace-all-white-spaces-with-commas-in-a-text-file

```
$ cat text.file | sed 's/[[:blank:]]\+/\ 0\ /g'

 0.0000000000 0 0.0000000000 0 0.0000000000 0
 0.7804643317 0 0.5703578412 0 0.0000000000 0
 -0.7804643317 0 0.5703578412 0 0.0000000000 0
```

or prettify with column:

```
$ cat text.file | sed 's/[[:blank:]]\+/\ 0\ /g' | column -t -e

 0.0000000000   0  0.0000000000  0  0.0000000000  0 
 0.7804643317   0  0.5703578412  0  0.0000000000  0
 -0.7804643317  0  0.5703578412  0  0.0000000000  0
```

Beware this accounts for empty spaces at the end of the string. Might want to filter with a prior sed.

```
 $ cat text.file | sed 's/[[:blank:]]\+$//g' | sed 's/[[:blank:]]\+/\ 0\ /g' | column -t -e

 0.0000000000   0  0.0000000000  0  0.0000000000 
 0.7804643317   0  0.5703578412  0  0.0000000000
 -0.7804643317  0  0.5703578412  0  0.0000000000
```

Comment: Note that you don't need cat there. You can give the file to sed as an argument. You also don't need to escape the spaces.

Comment: You probably want to use something like `[[: blank:]]\+\|$` (although there are spaces at the end of the example, newline is probably more common).